# How to remove empty lines when iterating by values?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've got xml data like this:

```xml
<root>
    <eee>aaa</eee>
    <eee>bbb</eee>
    <eee>ccc</eee>
    <eee>ddd</eee>
</root>
```

I want to displays elements `eee` in my `detail` band. Therefore I added `textField` that contains expression `$F{My_elem}` and I get:

> aaa 
>   bbb 
>  
>   ccc 
>   ddd

It looks pretty good but the problem is when I add "Print when" expression into my textField which is:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2==1
```

My report displays:

> aaa 
>    
>  
>    
>   ddd

But my aim is to display:

> aaa 
>   ddd

"Remove line when blank" set to TextField does't work.

How can I not display the blank line when details bound iterate by elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the "Print when" expression to the `detail` band

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2==1]]></printWhenExpression>
        .... your text fields...
    </band>
</detail>
```

This way instead of saying that your `textField` should not be displayed, you tell the report to remove the whole `detail` band

Comment: Your welcome thanks for accepted, I have edit your post, to have better title (as sentence) and formatted code and output differently... Have fun